# sencha touch build issue

Tags: build, dependencies, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I am using command "sencha app build testing" to deploy testing package.

I am getting following errors during creating testing build:

```
[WRN]           C1000: Yui Compressor Warning (Trailing comma is not legal in an ECMA-262 object initializer =>     },) -- C:\localdevelopment\apps\pressflow\ne w\pulse\app\app\view\DDEditor.js:2663
[INF]           Processing class inheritance graph
[INF]           Processing instantiation refereces to classes and aliases
[WRN]           C1000: Yui Compressor Warning (Trailing comma is not legal in an
 ECMA-262 object initializer =>     },) -- C:\localdevelopment\apps\pressflow\ne w\pulse\app\app\view\DDEditor.js:2663
[INF]           Processing source dependencies
[ERR]           Circular requires reference :
...\touch\src\AbstractComponent.js
...\touch\src\Evented.js ->
...\touch\src\core\src\util\TaskMan
ager.js ->
...\touch\src\util\TaskRunner.js ->

...\touch\src\util\Format.js ->
...\touch\src\core\src\util\TaskMan
ager.js
[ERR]
[ERR]           BUILD FAILED
[ERR]           com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException: The following error occurr
ed while executing this line:
[ERR]           ...\.sencha\app\bui
ld-impl.xml:137: com.sencha.exceptions.ExScript: Wrapped com.sencha.exceptions.B
asicException: com.sencha.exceptions.ExCircularReference: Circular requires refe
rence for file ...\touch\src\core\s
rc\util\TaskManager.js (x-app-build#273)   runAppBuild (x-app-build:273)   [anon
ymous] (x-app-build:545)   x_app_build (x-app-build:543)   <script> (anonymous:1
)
```

Please help to resolve these errors ...

Answer (score 0):

You have some typos in your code. That's what the

> [WRN]           C1000: Yui Compressor Warning (Trailing comma is not
>   legal in an ECMA-262 object initializer =>     },) --
>   C:\localdevelopment\apps\pressflow\ne
>   w\pulse\app\app\view\DDEditor.js:2663

is complaining. You have some extra commas somewhere in DDEditor.js.

The

> [ERR]           Circular requires reference :

says that you requiring extra classes in your project before you can use it. Take a look at this post 
http://bugsdaily.com/sencha-extjs-4/extjs-circular-requires-reference.html